# Time of CIBIL score update?

Tags: india, loans, credit-score, credit-report, credit-history

I have Education loan EMI of Rs 4500 per month. I didn't pay EMI for last 5 Months. So my cibil score has reduced to 600. I plan pay last 5 months EMI in a single payment and EMI regularly from this month. How much days or months  will it take to increase my cibil score. I don't have any other loans and credit cards.

And i applied 2 personal loans and 1 credit card. All are rejected because of low cibil score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay in repayment will remain in the report for 7 years.

Your score should show improvement in 6 months to an year.

Even after your score improves, you may still be asked questions about the default when you ask for credit

**Edit**

1. Every time you apply for a loan and there is an check on credit score, it reduces the score slightly. i.e. too many checks on credit score indicates one is desperate to get credit and hence lowers the score slightly.
2. You can monitor your own score for a small fee. Visit CIBIL website.
3. PAN is one per individual. You cannot apply for another PAN if you already have one. Its an criminal offense to have more than one PAN.

Comment: you may still be asked questions about the default when you ask for credit - I didn't understand

Comment: So let's say after 2 years your score becomes 750+. The report will still show that two and half years back you had a default, and may ask you why you defaulted.

Comment: oh ok ok. thanks. and i applied 2 personal loan and 1 credit card. All or within 45 days.all are rejected due to cibil score. will it reduce cibil score.

Comment: and i have another doubt. can i apply new PAN card and apply loans means will bank will approve it. is it good way?.